# UITabBar inside Master View

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I need to create an app with a Split View but I need to add a tab bar in the Master side of the split, I've read some stuff in this forum but I just can't get it right. 
I understand that when you have a split view you actually handle two view controllers the master and the detail so, to my understanding, if I need a tab bar in the master side I have to call the master from the appDelegate and inside this master I can set it up as a Tab Bar controller but either I have a complete misconception or I'm just implementing it wrong.

Here's what I'm doing in the appDelegate, as you can see I'm loading another VC than the master VC that comes with the template, my first question is if I have to load a VC or just an NSObject with the tab bar protocol?:

```
WTDInitialViewController *initialViewController = [[WTDInitialViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WTDInitialViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *initialNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:initialViewController];

    WTDDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[WTDDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WTDDetailViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

    self.splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
    self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:initialNavigationController, detailNavigationController, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
```

Now, this is what I do in the so called VC

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
    NSMutableArray *vcArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
    _tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    WTDMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[WTDMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WTDMasterViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
    _navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController];
    _navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    [vcArray addObject:_navigationController];

    _tabBarController.viewControllers = vcArray;
    _tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    [_window addSubview:_tabBarController.view];
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
return self;
```

It may be a stupid question but I hit a dead end so, any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm assuming you are creating SplitView for ipad. It's initial comes with MasterViewController and DetailViewController. And the MasterViewController is UITableview base, now you want to implement Tabbar base instead, then just call do this in ViewWillAppear of MasterViewController.

```
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[[YourTabView1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourTabView1" bundle:nil]autorelease];
//If you want the view support Navigation then do this
UINavigationController *tab1 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1]autorelease];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[[YourTabView2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourTabView2" bundle:nil]autorelease];
UINavigationController *tab2 = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2]autorelease];

UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabbarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:tab1,tab2,nil];

[self presentModalViewController:tabbarController animated:YES];
```

I think this should work(but I didnt test the code).